# Datetimepicker set value of different format

Tags: kendo-ui, datetimepicker

i want to set the kendo ui DateTimePicker to value with : `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`
(notice the order of dd & MM).

when i create the datetimepicker the firmat is :`"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`
and the value is `new Date(xxxx)`

when xxxx is "23/11/2013 09:15:30" nothing is presented in the picker
but when xxx is "11/23/2013 09:15:30" this date is presented.

how can i make it use `'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'` set format

thanks O.

Comment: provide which daertetime picker. Jquery?

Comment: Oh, sorry, kendo ui datetimepicker...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add both formats as parseFormat

```
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    format: "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt",
    parseFormats: ["MMMM yyyy", "HH:mm"] //format also will be added to parseFormats
});
```